# Ho do I restart the jenkins pipeline with an updated JenkinsFile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a Jenkins project with a declarative pipeline defined in a JenkinsFile stored in a SCM. I use the "Pipeline script from SCM" option.

Sometimes if something fails I do a quick fix in the jenkins workspace and rerun the pipeline starting at a specific stage. This is working nicely.

There are cases in which I need to update the JenkinsFile and then do a 'restart at stage' with the updated Jenkins file. However, I can't find the JenkinsFile anywhere in the workspace folder. I need to know the location so I can do a quick fix and then restart the pipeline. Where is the JenkinsFile located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ["Replay" Pipeline Runs with Modifications](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/#replay):

> The "Replay" feature allows for quick modifications and execution of an existing Pipeline without changing the Pipeline configuration or creating a new commit.